# Calling on attributes in python is not working

Tags: python-3.x, oop, attributes

I am having trouble understanding the issue behind my code, I am trying to call on attributes of an object using self.attribute but for some reason it is not working. This is the code:

```
import time
import string

class Book:
    """ This is a class with methods regarding the book itself """
    
    bookcopies = 0 #variable to keep track of bookcopies, initially = 0, once a book is added, update to 1

    def infofile(filename):
        books = []
        try:
            with open(filename, "r") as file:
                for line in file:
                    bookinfo = line.strip().split(",")
                    title,publisher,edition,year,month,language,paperback,isbn10,isbn13 = bookinfo
                    book = Book(title,publisher,int(edition),int(year),int(month),language,paperback,int(isbn10),int(isbn13))
                    books.append(book)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"File not found:{filename}")
        return books
    
    def displaybook(self):
        books = self.infofile(input("Enter File name:"))
        for book in books:
            print(f"Title:{self.title}")
            time.sleep(1)
            print(f"Publisher:{self.publisher}")
            time.sleep(1)
            print(f"Edition:{self.edition}")
            time.sleep(1)
            print(f"Year:{self.year}")
            time.sleep(1)
            print(f"Month:{self.month}")
            time.sleep(1)
            print(f"Language:{self.language}")
            time.sleep(1)
            print(f"Paperback:{self.paperback}")
            time.sleep(1)
            print(f"ISBN-10:{self.isbn10}")
            time.sleep(1)
            print(f"ISBN-13:{self.isbn13}")
        

    def __init__(self, title, publisher, edition): #add isbn, year, month...etc and maintain code structure. 
        self.title = title
        self.publisher = publisher
        self.edition = edition

    def editbook(self, newtitle, newpublisher, newedition): #add isbn, year,..etc and maintain code structure. 
        self.title = newtitle
        self.publsiher = newpublisher
        self.edition = newedition
```

I tried re running the code, erasing and rewriting, but I think it might be me misusing the code because I am not used to python OOP.

EDIT :-
It is a simple syntax error/typo which was caused in the `def editbook()` function. As it should be `self.publisher = newpublisher`. It has been rectified as mentioned by the original author of the post

Comment: `self.publsiher = newpublisher` You have a typo here.

Comment: I think I found the problem, in my init function, I forgot to write the rest of the attributes like month, year...etc. It is funny I even added a comment to add them yet proceeded to ignore the comment and complain